# Using integer keys with dot notation to access property in javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

Why can't we use integer keys in dot expression to access property values ?

```
var obj = {1: 'one', two: '2'}
console.log(obj.1) // error
console.log(obj.two)
```

Comment: I think due to the limitation of naming convention of javascript variable.

Comment: 1 is represented as string internally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) to access a value, the property key must be a valid identifier

> In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a
>   sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore
>   ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For
>   example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) in this case

```
obj['1']
```

Spec: [Property Accessors](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors)

Comment: The last link is broken.

Comment: @rooby I changed it to https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Arun P Johny' s answer
we can use `obj['1']` with quotes or `obj[1]` without quotes in case of integer.
where as accessing `obj['two']` will work but `obj[two]` will throw an error if there is no variable/constant as **two**.

Answer (score -2):

It is a JavaScript base princible which says variables cannot start with a number. Over here the property is a variable and hence it cannot start with a number.

You can check more about variable definition rules [here](http://www.codelifter.com/main/tips/tip_020.shtml)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference since it is now dead

Comment: Property names are not variables.