# How to fix vscode auto spacing issues in react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to save some data into a state using object keys in react,

Ex : setText(data[listname][0].feature-type;

But after saving the file it automatically adding a space between featute and type

Ex: setText(data[listname][0].feature - type:

As it is this will resulted as reference error.How to avoid this

Comment: Is feature-type a property? You need to access as a dictionary `setText(data[listname][0]['feature-type']`. Because there are some limitations to which names can be accessed with a dot (.). And since the property name contains hífen (-), it needs to be accessed as a dictionary. VSCode is formatting different then what you expect because you are giving it invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, this is the solution if feature-type is a property of the object you are trying to access:

You need to access it as a dictionary `setText(data[listname][0]['feature-type']`.

Because there are some limitations to which names can be accessed with a dot (.). And since the property name contains hífen (-), it needs to be accessed as a dictionary. VSCode is formatting different then what you expect because you are giving it invalid syntax.

You can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888297/8633918 for more details.